# Yaml merging from docker using a python script

Tags: python, docker, merge, yaml, dockerfile

I'd like to merge multiple Yaml file from a repo in a single file to use it on a container.

I did the following script, which work well :

```
from os import path, walk, getenv
import yaml
import locale

def mergeYaml(directory):
    all_ = []

    for root, dirs, files in walk(directory):
        for dir_ in dirs:
            for root2, dirs2, files2 in walk(root+"/"+dir_):
                for file_ in files2:
                    with open("{}/{}".format(root2, file_), 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
                        all_.append(yaml.safe_load(f))

    return all_
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = getenv("DIRECTORY", "/repo")

    if(not path.exists("./device-type.yml")):
        res = mergeYaml(base)

        with open("./device-type.yml", 'w') as file:
            yaml.dump(res, file, sort_keys=True, explicit_start=True)
```

This work  well, as i have one single device-type.yml file with all my .yaml as an array item.

---

Now, i need this to be done from a Docker image, so i created the following Dockerfile:

```
# Build image
FROM alpine/git as git

WORKDIR /repo
RUN git clone --single-branch -- https://URL /repo

# Final image 
FROM python:3-slim

ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
##
#
COPY --from=git /repo /repo
WORKDIR /app
ADD main.py app.py
##
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pyaml
RUN ["python3","-u","app.py"]
##
#
```

Building this generate the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 22, in <module>
    res = mergeYaml(base)
  File "/app/app.py", line 13, in mergeYaml
    all_.append(yaml.safe_load(f))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 162, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 112, in load
    loader = Loader(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/loader.py", line 34, in __init__
    Reader.__init__(self, stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.determine_encoding()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 124, in determine_encoding
    self.update_raw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 178, in update_raw
    data = self.stream.read(size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 11: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried lots of things, like forcing UTF8 (but i assume this is applied by defautl, as i checked the env LANG=C.UTF-8 when a fresh python:3-slim image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the contents of `/repo` with `git clone`, which results in a `.git` folder. Python's `os.walk` includes hidden files, so it will descend into the `.git` folder and try to parse files there.

You can do something like this to not clone, but simply get the content of a branch:

```
git archive --remote=https://URL HEAD | tar -x -C /repo
```

Alternatively, you can filter your directories for `.git` or generally hidden directories in your script, or filter the files for extension.

For better debugging, you could print out the files your script tries to process.

Comment: Wonderfull, wasn't thinking about .git issues, thanks !